# Advice for nightmare backyard project

Tags: bmw

I have a BMW 335i and three months ago the oil lines on the turbo started leaking oil super bad. With the help of a friend I took it all apart - the engine is on a hoist, the subframe exhaust and the entire front end has been taken apart and all those parts are sitting in a giant pile in my back yard. I'm at the point where I need help putting it all back together but I have had a nightmare of a time finding a mechanic to help me.

At this point no mechanic shop in their right mind would touch it, being completely disassembled.  I'm starting to feel like this will never get done. The mechanics I've tried to hire off of craigslist have been completely and utterly disastrous.  The last guy I had come take a look started to blatantly rob me, stealing tools and parts, and when I called him out he pulled a knife on me.  So I am done taking the craigslist route.

Money is not the problem here; I would gladly pay $1000 to have a competent Mechanic finish this.

One problem is that it is freezing cold outside now; there is snow on the ground. I can't finish this by myself for a few reasons - the subframe oil pan and stuff are two man minimum. Also I'm in over my head from a technical and physical standpoint.

On the other hand,  The remaining work it is not that difficult. There is maybe a good 6-10 hours left. All the hard stuff is done; the lines are off, I have all new parts that just need to be bolted on.

I'm at the end of my rope! What should I do?? Any advice would be most appreciated.  I wonder if anyone else has been in my shoes...

I am in the greater Seattle area by the way.

Comment: maybe check out BMW clubs / forums or local car groups?  might find someone willing to wrench with you just to hang out and drink some beers.

Comment: This is the wrong direction for this question to take, but have you considered trying Angie's List? Also, rpmerf raised a great point - there are lots of enthusiasts in local clubs and forums. But in order to be able to network into that resource, I suspect you're going to need to immerse yourself in their culture. If you've got time for that, you should.. especially getting out there and meeting club members in person.

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to get a competent mechanic to sort this - but because of the issue you have already raised, this is going to cost you a lot of money. They do not know how much you have messed up by taking it to pieces, and to be fair, if you have got to the point of disassembling and have got stuck, you are not in a strong negotiating position.

I did the same with my motorbike - I **could** have completed it and rebuilt myself, but there were so many potential issues and I didn't know what I would find as I completed the disassembly, that it could have taken years. So I took the lot to a garage and agreed that I would cover all costs - parts and labour. So it did end up costing much more than it should, but is almost complete now.

To me that was worthwhile, as I actually just want to get out on it. You'll need to weigh up pros and cons for yourself.